# Approvers Field Missing when Initiating a Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, workflow, approval-process

I'm trying to set up a workflow for document approval using (what I think are) the default workflows provided in SharePoint. After I set up the workflow and go to a document to initiate it, the approvers field is missing and cannot be edited (see image below). I can edit this field in the workflow setting and assign people but I want to be able to be able assign people when stating the workflow. I have tried to figure out what has is causing the but no luck.

Hoping someone is able to help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below tips, compare the results.

1.Create a new build-in approval workflow associated with this list.

2.Create a new approval workflow associated with the list in this SharePoint Designer.

3.Create a new build-in approval workflow in other lists and site collections.

4.Deactivate and re-activate "Workflow Task Content Type" feature in the site features.

5.Deactivate and re-activate "Three-state workflow" and "Workflows" features in the site collection features.

Similar question:[Some fields are missing in Current Task - Designer Workflow Approval Task Process](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c4301b19-606e-40fe-b750-1ee174f35fc5/some-fields-are-missing-in-current-task-designer-workflow-approval-task-process?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)